# Does the Blu-ray of Peter Jackson's King Kong (2005) have the recreated "spider pit sequence"?

Tags: distribution, alternate-version, king-kong-2005

A spider pit scene was shot for the original 1933 King Kong, but was presumably cut from the film due to graphic content and is now considered as lost. [Peter Jackson reshot the scene](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0832446/) using contemporary technology during the filming of his remake. [Wired confirms that the scene is included on the Collector's Edition DVD](https://www.wired.com/2006/12/king-kongs-lost/), but did it ever make its way to the Blu-ray release?

Answer (score 1):

The Blu - Ray, and indeed every other release of Peter Jackson's 2005 *King Kong* includes Jackson's version of the 'Spider - Pit' scene, as it was not actually removed from the theatrical release.

[image]

The most significant Skull Island island based action sequence that was removed from the theatrical cut (and which was restored in the directors 'special edition' - the cut included on the 2005 DVD Deluxe Edition' and on the standard Region B BD release of the film) involved the crossing of the swamp and the 'Piranhadon' attack.

Of course, having completely got the wrong end of the stick there (you are talking about his remake of Willis's actual scene) the feature was not originally included on the standard BD release but may yet be available on this beaut...

[image]

and if not can be watched here in the meantime...

[King Kong (1933): The Lost Spider Pit Sequence - Peter Jackson Recreation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOMKnhN7ABs)